# PHP простая система комментирования на сайте без SQL

Tags: php

Подскажите почему не выводятся комментарии?

```
<?php
   $data = date("Y-m-d");
   if (isset($_POST[''])); 
   $file = fopen('comments.txt','a+'); 
   fputs($file,$_POST['name']); 
   fputs($file,$_POST['komment']); 
   fclose($file); 
   ?>
   <pre><?include ("comments.txt")?></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?include`
- не пишите функции слитно с открывающим тегом.
- Если пишите короткий синтаксис `<?` вместо полного `<?php`, убедитесь что он включен или пишите полностью `<?php`

- попробуйте так:

`<?php include ("comments.txt")?>`

- Еще способ получить содержимое файла:
  `$comment = file_get_contents('comments.txt'); 
  echo $comment;`

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, спасибо, вопрос закрыт.

```
     <?php
         error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
         $name_page_post = trim(mb_ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Za-яА-ЯЁё0-9]", '-', 
         $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
         $data = date("Y-m-d");
         $komment = $_POST['komment'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $name = $_POST['name'];
         $text = '';
         $text .= "Дата: $data \n";
         $text .= "Им'я: $name \n"; 
         $text .= "Пошта: $email \n"; 
         $text .= "Відгук: $komment \n";
            if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($komment)) 
         {
         $file = fopen ("comments.txt", "a+");
         fwrite ($file,$text); 
         fclose ($file); 
        }
     ?>

     <?php
        $filename = 'comments.txt';
        $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);
        echo $contents;
     ?>
```